# Append element with SAX in python

Tags: python, xml, sax

I know how to parse xml with sax in python, but how would I go about inserting elements into the document i'm parsing? Do I have to create a separate file?

Could someone provide a simple example or alter the one I've put below. Thanks.

---

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
from xml.sax import make_parser
import sys

class aHandler(ContentHandler):

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        print "<",name,">"

    def characters(self, content):
        print content

    def endElement(self,name):
        print "</",name,">"


handler = aHandler()
saxparser = make_parser()
saxparser.setContentHandler(handler)

datasource = open("settings.xml","r")
saxparser.parse(datasource)
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<names>
    <name>
      <first>First1</first>
      <second>Second1</second>
    </name>
    <name>
      <first>First2</first>
      <second>Second2</second>
    </name>
    <name>
      <first>First3</first>
      <second>Second3</second>
    </name>
</names>
```

Comment: What elements do you want to insert? What are they're content? When you get an endElement callback, can you just print the extra element?

Comment: I don't just want to print an element, I want to insert it into the file I'm parsing.

Answer (score 0):

With DOM, you have the entire xml structure in memory.
With SAX, you don't have a DOM available, so you don't have anything to append an element to.

The main reason for using SAX is if the xml structure is really, really huge-- if it would be a serious performance hit to place the DOM in memory. If that isn't the case (as it appears to be from your small sample xml file), I would always use DOM vs. SAX.

If you go the DOM route, (which seems to be the only option to me), look into [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). It's one of the best python xml libraries around.

Comment: I have simple example code because it would be easiest to learn from, but I intend to parse a very large (about 200MB) file.

Comment: In that case, the only way I could think to accomplish this would be for your SAX handler to capture every possible event, and repeat them back to another handler that creates a separate file. If you want to insert an element into a 200MB file and have it persist to disk, you'll somehow have to write to disk a 200MB file.